# Netbeans Field Validation (Alphabetical\Numerical\Lenght)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, validation, netbeans

First i'd like to mention that i've been researching about this for few days and although i found some answers that should have been helpful i was unable to use them correctly due to the fact that i am not that much into programming yet and got no experience and might be missing something.

Straight to the point, i have a registration form and i need field validation i already have the one that validate email and empty fields for others but i need to add to the code a part that would reject numerical entries in name fields and alphabetical characters for ID field and to limit the length of a field.

Let's start with the Name field which i want to allow alphabetical characters only here is my current code:

```
{
var fn=document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value;
if (fn==null || fn=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
```

And that's my ID field which i want to limit to numerical entries only

```
   var id=document.forms["myForm"]["ID"].value;
  if (id==null || id=="")
  {
  alert("ID must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
```

I want to a couple of lines that would limit entries to a specific number of characters as well, how do i do that?

Comment: This looks like a javascript question.

Answer (score 0):

To check for a string length in Javascript you can use the .length method:

```
// this checks if the fn length is more than 10
if (fn.length > 10) {
}
```

To check if a value is numeric you can parse it and make sure that returns a valid output:

```
// This checks if id is not a valid integer
if (isNaN(parseInt(id)) {
}
```

To check if a value is alphabetical only you have to make sure the characters in it fall within the alphabets range, you can add a function that checks for that:

```
// This loops on every character of value and makes sure it is part of the letters string
function isAlphabetical (value) {
    var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    for (i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        if (letters.indexOf(value.charAt(i), 0) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then call it from your if statement:

```
// This checks if fn is not alphabetical
if (!isAlphabetical(fn)) {

}
```